# Problem involving Outer Measure

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Below is my attempt at the solution of a problem involving outer measure.

$\textbf{Problem:}$  For sets $A$ and $B$, prove that if $m^{*}(A)=0$, then $m^{*}(A \cup B)= m^{*}(B).$

$\textbf{Solution:}$ The monotonicity of $m^{*}$ gives us that $m^{*}(B) \leq m^{*}(A \cup B)$. To prove the reverse inequality, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We know there exists an open set $G$ such that $B \subseteq G$ and $$m^{*}(B) \leq m^{*}(G) \leq m^{*}(B) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ By our assumption, we know there exists an open set $G’$ such that $A \subseteq G’$ and such that $m^{*}(G’) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ The open sets $G$ and $G’$ both have unique representations as countably-many disjoint open intervals. Suppose $G = \bigcup I_{n}$ and $G’ = \bigcup J_{n}$. Then, by definition, $m^{*}(G)= \sum m^{*}(I_{n})$ and $m^{*}(G’)= \sum m^{*}(J_n)$. Next, note that $G \cup G’$ covers $A \cup B$. The set $G \cup G’$ is, of course, an open set and has a unique representation as countably-many disjoint open intervals , say $G \cup G’ = \bigcup K_{n}.$ Then, \begin{eqnarray}m^{*}(A \cup B) \leq m^{*}(G \cup G’) &=& \sum m^{*}(K_{n})\\ &\leq&  \sum m^{*}(I_{n}) + \sum m^{*}(J_n )\\ &=& m^{*}(G) + m^{*}(G’) \\ &\leq& m^{*}(B) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\ &=& m^{*}(B) + \epsilon.\end{eqnarray}Finally, because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude the reverse inclusion and, consequently, our desired result.  $\blacksquare$

**Question:** I feel that those infinite sums are correct; however, when going over my solution I had a hard time convincing myself that I didn't do anything wrong. Can someone please verify? Or, if I am mistaken, can someone please point out the error? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The outer measure is countably sub-additive, so to prove the reverse inequality you can simply say that $m^*(A \cup B) \le m^*(A)+m^*(B) =0+m^*(B)=m^*(B)$